# Should I split an SQL query across multiple processes and merge the result?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, multithreading

I’ve set up a MySQL database with large table that I’m querying using a join and also checking if the value in a column is in a list that is extremely long (the list is 10k+ integers). I’ve tried setting up a temporary table with this list and it didn’t speed things up.

I’m querying using Python, and what I was wondering was if it would be more efficient to use multiprocessing to send off 8 queries simultaneously and split my list of integers into eighths?

Comment: When you create the temporary table, make the single column a clustered primary key.

Comment: So in MySQL I would just say 'colname CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY' and that will help speed it up?

Comment: Actually `primary key` is probably sufficient.